# Errors and warnings with GStreamer are they undermining my output?

Tags: python, video, gstreamer, opencv

I am using a Python3 script to split video clips (.mp4) into frames (.png images). To do so I use opencv (cv2) methods.

```
import cv2
import os

dataset_folder = 'Video-dataset/'
save_path = 'Video-dataset-images/'

if not os.path.exists(save_path):
    os.mkdir(save_path)

videos_list = os.listdir(dataset_folder)
video_ids = [re.findall("[0-9_]*", video)[0] for video in videos]

for video in video_ids:
    video_path = dataset_folder + video + ".mp4"
    save_name = save_path + video
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
    fps_count = 0
    for i in range(fps):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            cv2.imwrite(save_name+str(10000+fps_count)+'.png', frame)
            fps_count += 1
```

I get the actual video clips splitted into images, however I get also the following echoes from the script :

> [ INFO:0] VIDEOIO: Enabled backends(7, sorted by priority):
>   FFMPEG(1000); GSTREAMER(990); V4L2(980); CV_IMAGES(970);
>   CV_MJPEG(960); FIREWIRE(950); GPHOTO2(940)
>
> (python3.6:12757): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 13:40:56.545:
>   gst_element_make_from_uri: assertion 'gst_uri_is_valid (uri)' failed
>   GStreamer: Error opening bin: no element "Video-dataset"
>
> (python3.6:12757): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 13:40:56.545:
>   gst_element_get_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed [
>   WARN:0] VideoCapture(filename=Video-dataset/01.mp4) was built without
>   support of requested backendID=300
>
> (python3.6:12757): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 13:41:18.943:
>   gst_element_make_from_uri: assertion 'gst_uri_is_valid (uri)' failed
>   GStreamer: Error opening bin: no element "Video-dataset"
>
> (python3.6:12757): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 13:41:18.943:
>   gst_element_get_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed [
>   WARN:0] VideoCapture(filename=Video-dataset/03.mp4) was built without
>   support of requested backendID=300
>
> (python3.6:12757): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 13:41:19.331:
>   gst_element_make_from_uri: assertion 'gst_uri_is_valid (uri)' failed
>   GStreamer: Error opening bin: no element "Video-dataset"
>
> (python3.6:12757): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 13:41:19.331:
>   gst_element_get_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed [
>   WARN:0] VideoCapture(filename=Video-dataset/10.mp4) was built without
>   support of requested backendID=300
>
> (python3.6:12757): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 13:41:25.879:
>   gst_element_make_from_uri: assertion 'gst_uri_is_valid (uri)' failed
>   GStreamer: Error opening bin: no element "Video-dataset"
>
> (python3.6:12757): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 13:41:25.879:
>   gst_element_get_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed [
>   WARN:0] VideoCapture(filename=Video-dataset/15.mp4) was built without
>   support of requested backendID=300
>
> (python3.6:12757): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 13:41:31.485:
>   gst_element_make_from_uri: assertion 'gst_uri_is_valid (uri)' failed
>   GStreamer: Error opening bin: no element "Video-dataset"
>
> (python3.6:12757): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 13:41:31.485:
>   gst_element_get_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed [
>   WARN:0] VideoCapture(filename=Video-dataset/27.mp4) was built without
>   support of requested backendID=300
>
> (python3.6:12757): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 13:41:38.932:
>   gst_element_make_from_uri: assertion 'gst_uri_is_valid (uri)' failed
>   GStreamer: Error opening bin: no element "Video-dataset"
>
> (python3.6:12757): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 13:41:38.932:
>   gst_element_get_state: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed [
>   WARN:0] VideoCapture(filename=Video-dataset/34.mp4) was built without
>   support of requested backendID=300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally understood the problem, this line of code is erroneous, because a small number of videos have alphanumeric names.

```
video_ids = [re.findall("[0-9_]*", video)[0] for video in videos]
```

Moreover, these same videos are of .avi extensions which I exclude in the loop.